# Why ZFC+FOL cannot uniquely describe/characterize $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{N}$?

Tags: set-theory, first-order-logic

I find the following text on the Wikipedia page on first order logic:

> First-order logic is the standard for the formalization of mathematics into axioms and is studied in the foundations of mathematics. Peano arithmetic and Zermelo–Fraenkel set theory are axiomatizations of number theory and set theory, respectively, into first-order logic. No first-order theory, however, has the strength to ***uniquely describe*** a structure with an infinite domain, such as the natural numbers or the real line. Axioms systems that do fully describe these two structures (that is, categorical axiom systems) can be obtained in stronger logics such as second-order logic.

Here, what I want to ask is what does uniquely describe/characterize mean? Why is it that $\textbf{FOL}$ cannot uniquely describe/characterize $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{N}$?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Why is it that FOL . . . cannot uniquely describe/characterize $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{N}$?

Here's the precise statement: if $\Phi$ is *any* set of first order sentences true in $\mathcal{N}=(\mathbb{N}; +, \times)$, then there is a structure $\mathcal{A}$ such that

- The sentences in $\Phi$ are also true in $\mathcal{A}$, and
- $\mathcal{A}\not\cong\mathcal{N}$.

That is, no set of first-order sentences characterizes $\mathcal{N}$ *up to isomorphism.* The same is true for any other infinite structure.

This is a consequence of the [**compactness theorem**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compactness_theorem) for first-order logic; but you may also be interested in the [Lowenheim-Skolem theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6wenheim%E2%80%93Skolem_theorem), which describes another fundamental obstacle to describing structures in first-order logic.

---

Belatedly incorporating and expanding on an observation by [Vladimir Kanovei](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1978554/28111), if we're a bit flexible about our requirements and push a little into the second-order realm we can find a lot of positive results:

- $\mathcal{N}=(\mathbb{N}; +,\times)$ is characterizable up to isomorphism as the **minimal** model of a particular first-order theory.
- By the downward Lowenheim-Skolem theorem no minimality characterization is possible for the field $\mathcal{R}=(\mathbb{R};+,\times)$, and compactness (in its guise as the upward Lowenheim-Skolem theorem) prevents any maximality characterization for any infinite structure whatsoever. However, $\mathcal{R}$ is characterizable as the **maximal** model of the first-order theory of real closed fields which additionally *omits* the partial type describing an infinite element (= is Archimedean).

  - Interestingly, $\mathcal{R}$ is **not** the maximal *rigid* real closed field. There are in fact rigid non-archimedean real closed fields. Weirdly, it is [currently open](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/293463/rigid-non-archimedean-real-closed-fields) whether *countable* rigid non-Archimedean real closed fields exist!
- Somewhat less naturally, $\mathcal{R}^-=(\mathbb{R};+,<)$ is the **minimal** model of the first-order theory of divisible ordered abelian groups which **realizes** every type over a countable set of parameters which is bounded above and has ordertype $\omega$.

It's worth noting that $(i)$ pretty much every naturally-occurring structure *can* be described up to isomorphism by a *second-order* theory or even sentence *([Vaananen](http://www.math.helsinki.fi/logic/people/jouko.vaananen/Vaananen_Compass.pdf): "the ordered structure
of the natural numbers, the complete separable Archimedian field of reals
numbers, the complex field, as well as practically all commonly occurring
mathematical structures have a categorical second order axiomatisation")*, and $(ii)$ we usually only need a small fragment of $\mathsf{SOL}$ to do this.

Comment: What about [this?](http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781447115939) I've discovered Eudoxus reals some time ago and it seems that they can be used to prove things about the reals. I'm not sure if it is FOL or not.

Comment: @OppaHilbertStyle That isn't relevant. The Eudoxus, and Cauchy and Dedekind, constructions give descriptions of $\mathbb{R}$ *inside a larger structure* - namely, a model of ZFC. These constructions are all appropriately first-order, but they rely on the ambient model of set theory. The same holds for $\mathbb{N}$: each model of ZFC has a "copy" of $\mathbb{N}$ sitting inside it, which can be defined in a first-order way inside the structure; but different models' versions of $\mathbb{N}$ will be nonisomorphic.

Answer (score 4):

A concrete way of viewing this phenomenon is to note that the ultrapower of a given model $M$ will produce a new model ${}^\ast\! M$ which can easily be shown to be nonisomorphic to $M$.  It is an elementary extension of $M$ by Los's theorem. The construction of the ultrapower can be carried out in ZFC.  Note that to apply compactness theorems you will typically also require some form of the axiom of choice.

Here $\mathbb N$ and $\mathbb R$ are sometimes claimed be to *categorical*.  Two remarks are in order.

(1) Whatever the merits of the claimed categoricity, it requires more than first order logic.  For example, to characterize the reals we need the completeness property which requires a quantifier running over all subsets of $\mathbb R$.

(2) The categoricity is dependent on a background model of ZFC.  Model-dependence is sometimes concealed behind talk about *intended models* or *intended interpretations*; see e.g., [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/232584/looking-for-a-source-for-intended-interpretation) for a discussion. In different models of ZFC the natural numbers will behave very differently, and similarly for the reals.

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to interpret this question, and the distinction is indeed important.

Working *inside* a universe of $\sf ZFC$, using first-order logic *inside* the universe, it is indeed impossible to characterize $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb N$, as Noah wrote. Using one of myriad of methods (Lowenheim-Skolem theorems, compactness, ultrapowers) we can produce models with the same theory as $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb N$ which have a completely different cardinality. In fact, we can even produce models of the same cardinality which are not isomorphic to them.

At the same time, one can interpret this as asking, assuming that we work with framework of first-order logic and $\sf ZFC$. Can we uniquely characterize the reals or the natural numbers? Namely, we work *inside* a fixed universe of $\sf ZFC$, with first-order logic as the underlying logic. Can we characterize the natural numbers or the real numbers *inside* the model? The answer to that is "yes, up to isomorphism (inside the model)". What we can prove is that:

1. There exists a set which represents the natural numbers, and there exists a set which represents the real numbers.
2. Any other object $X$ inside the model, that the model satisfies the condition "$X$ is a well-founded model of Peano" or "$X$ is a Dedekind-complete ordered field" is isomorphic---inside the model---to the natural numbers or the real numbers respectively.

In fact, this is why we bother using first-order logic and set theory as a foundation. Second-order logic has no proof verification algorithm. So instead of using second-order logic on the natural numbers, we instead prove that $\sf ZFC$ proves such and such, and thus transforming a second, or third, or higher order logic statements into a first-order statement in the language of set theory. And since first-order logic *does* have an algorithmic method of verifying if something is a valid proof, this means that we can program a computer to check if our proof is sound.

Comment: Please enlighten me where the answer is problematic, and I'd be happy to fix it. Unless, of course, the problem lies with the author.

Comment: I certainly didn't downvote, but/and possibly people disagree so strongly with your last paragraph (both premises and conclusions) that they ... react. But at the very least that paragraph (and the rest of this answer, to my perception) add useful information not duplicated in other answers...

Comment: @paul: Thank you for the comment. I don't know about the first downvote; but the second one was a retaliatory downvote (and the person also admitted to have done that). I will try to think of a better way to phrase it, which may be less... antagonizing to certain people. Thanks!

Comment: I didn't downvote either, but I think your phrasing is not very clear. The first point you wrote had "inside a universe of ZFC, using first-order logic inside the universe" while the second point had "inside a fixed universe of ZFC, with first-order logic as the underlying logic". Frankly I can't see the difference between the two, although I know perfectly well what the facts are. Perhaps you should just say that ZFC proves that the first-order theory of $\mathbb{N}$ has non-isomorphic models, but that there is a unique model that is well-founded (or that satisfies second-order induction).

Comment: @paulgarrett: But I don't understand what is problematic with the last paragraph. One only needs a very weak meta-system to prove that second-order logic (with full semantics) does not have decidable proof verification, and certainly if we have a proof verification algorithm we can indeed check if our proof is sound, unless of course one rejects even the validity of the collection of natural numbers (satisfying PA)!

Comment: @user21820, I don't disagree with anything in that last paragraph, but only note that other people might, or might react (arguably irrationally), based on philosophical prejudices about foundations and such.

Comment: @user21820: You are right, both readings share the fact "we work inside a fixed universe", but in one case we can understand that as "can we describe a fully categorical theory in FOL [add relevant assumptions]", where the answer is no; and the other is "Assume that we work in ZFC+FOL, can we fully characterize this and that", in which case the answer is yes. The difference here is what does FOL mean. Is FOL the *internal* FOL or the *external* meta-theoretic framework?

Comment: But that's the problem. Both are the same FOL, just that a first-order theory of PA cannot pin down **N**, at least from the viewpoint of ZF, while there is a way to pin down **N** using the language of ZF itself, but again just from the viewpoint of ZF. In the latter, every model of ZF has a unique **N** for it. I think if you used more precise terminology the issue will go away, because at present I don't think one who does not already understand the matter at hand can fully get your answer, though if they ignore those two parts then the rest should tell them what they need. =)

Comment: That sounds like a great way to procrastinate writing a research proposal for my postdoc application. Unfortunately, I cannot afford this right now. Next Monday, however, I'll have more time. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: @AsafKaragila: You're most welcome, and all the best for your postdoc application! =)

Answer (score 2):

Still to some extent $\mathbb N$ is characterisable in FOL plus a small increment. The increment being the non-FOL requirement of being a least structure satisfying some list of axioms (Peano's axioms in the FOL version for $\mathbb N$). What about $\mathbb R$ ?

Comment: By the downward and upward Lowenheim-Skolem theorems, $\mathbb{R}$ cannot be pinned down as either a minimal *or* maximal model of any countable first-order theory. However, we can come close to this: for instance, $\mathbb{R}$ as an ordered field is up to isomorphism the unique maximal model of the ordered field axioms (which are first-order) which omits the partial type of an infinite element (= is Archimedean). In general we can use omitting/realizing requirements in conjunction with minimality/maximality properties to characterize models well beyond what FOL is, strictly, capable of doing.